# Convert a file of messed-up encoding type to something usable

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm trying to clean up the *contents* of the page for the following link, obtained by a SPARQL query :

```
http://www.rechercheisidore.fr/sparql/query?query=PREFIX+dcterms%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E+PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E+SELECT+%3Furicollection+%3Ftitrecollection+%3Fdescription+%3Fadresseweb+WHERE+{+%3Furicollection+%3Fpredicat+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.rechercheisidore.fr%2Fclass%2FCollection%3E.+%3Furicollection+dcterms%3Atitle+%3Ftitrecollection.+%3Furicollection+dcterms%3Adescription+%3Fdescription.+%3Furicollection+foaf%3Ahomepage+%3Fadresseweb.+}+ORDER+BY+ASC%28%3Ftitrecollection%29+LIMIT+300&format=application%2Frdf%2Bxml
```

The page is in French. Every letter with an accent is not shown correctly, and when trying to replace the characters with the good ones in Python, it returns me errors. I tried to convert the file to UTF-8 but that didn't solve anything (actually it's already in utf-8) hence the idea of messed-up enconding (an engineer from the website confirmed it was a bug in their triple-store). An example : instead of `Ã©` you should see `é`.

I would like to have a file upon with I could at least use the python 2.7 `str.replace()` function to get back the correct characters -- or is there a better way to achieve this?

Sample from the RDF XML file demonstrating the problem:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:res="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="rset">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#ResultSet" />
    <res:resultVariable>uricollection</res:resultVariable>
    <res:resultVariable>titrecollection</res:resultVariable>
    <res:resultVariable>description</res:resultVariable>
    <res:resultVariable>adresseweb</res:resultVariable>
    <res:solution rdf:nodeID="r0">
      <res:binding rdf:nodeID="r0c0"><res:variable>uricollection</res:variable><res:value rdf:resource="http://www.rechercheisidore.fr/resource/10670/3.ewe76u"/></res:binding>
      <res:binding rdf:nodeID="r0c1"><res:variable>titrecollection</res:variable><res:value>ActualitÃ©s de l&#39;Ecole des Hautes Etudes en Sciences Sociales</res:value></res:binding>
      <res:binding rdf:nodeID="r0c2"><res:variable>description</res:variable><res:value>L&#39;Ãcole des hautes Ã©tudes en sciences sociales (EHESS), est issue de la transformation, en 1975, de la sixiÃ¨me section de l&#39;Ãcole pratique des hautes Ã©tudes, section de sciences Ã©conomiques et sociales, fondÃ©e en 1947 par Lucien Febvre, Charles MorazÃ© et Fernand Braudel. L&#39;EHESS occupe une place singuliÃ¨re dans le paysage franÃ§ais de la recherche. Elle forme des docteurs dans toutes les disciplines des sciences humaines et sociales, mais elle n&#39;est pas une universitÃ©.</res:value></res:binding>
      <res:binding rdf:nodeID="r0c3"><res:variable>adresseweb</res:variable><res:value rdf:resource="http://www.ehess.fr"/></res:binding>
    </res:solution>
```

Comment: I don't see. What are the serious encoding problems that are supposed to be there? All I see is an URL-encoded query string. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I see non-English words. Not sure what language the file was supposed to be in...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not trying to clean the URL but the resulting page.

Comment: @CppLearner The page is in french. Every letter with an accent is not shown correctly, and when trying to replace the charactters with the good ones in Python, it returns me errors. I tried to convert the file to UTF-8 but that didn't solve anything (actually it's already in utf-8) hence the idea of messed-up enconding (an engineer from the website confirmed it was a bug in their triple-store). An example : instead of Ã© you should see é.

Comment: @hyogapag: then include the data from the URL **here**. The URL might be gone at some point making your question useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the page appears to be that the server encoded the text as UTF-8 and then treated the UTF-8 as Latin-1 and encoded it in UTF-8 *again*.  To reverse this, read the file in as UTF-8, encode it as a Latin-1 string of bytes, and then decode the bytes as UTF-8.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, and seems quite logical afterwards. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Corroboration of jwodder's solution:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import urllib2

url = "http://www.rechercheisidore.fr/sparql/query?query=PREFIX+dcterms:+<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>+PREFIX+foaf:+<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>+SELECT+?uricollection+?titrecollection+?description+?adresseweb+WHERE+{+?uricollection+?predicat+<http://www.rechercheisidore.fr/class/Collection>.+?uricollection+dcterms:title+?titrecollection.+?uricollection+dcterms:description+?description.+?uricollection+foaf:homepage+?adresseweb.+}+ORDER+BY+ASC(?titrecollection)+LIMIT+300&format=application/rdf+xml"
doc = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))

namespaces = { 'ns':'http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#', }

for elt in doc.xpath('//ns:binding[@name="description"]/ns:literal',
                     namespaces=namespaces):
    text = elt.text
    if text is not None:
        text = text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf_8')
        print(text)
    break
```

yields

```
L'École des hautes études en sciences sociales (EHESS), est issue de la transformation, en 1975, de la sixième section de l'École pratique des hautes études, section de sciences économiques et sociales, fondée en 1947 par Lucien Febvre, Charles Morazé et Fernand Braudel. L'EHESS occupe une place singulière dans le paysage français de la recherche. Elle forme des docteurs dans toutes les disciplines des sciences humaines et sociales, mais elle n'est pas une université.
```

Comment: Your lines where very helpful. Unfortunately I can't mark your answer as useful, because I don't have enough credit. Thank you very much.